# Integration Services Import Project Wizard from command line

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I have around 100 .ispac files and I need to create SSIS project for every of them.
Is any way to do it programmatically?
Maybe there is some .exe file that starts Integration Services Import Project Wizard and can be executed with some parameters?